# findByIdAndUpdate keeps being caught in .catch

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, postman, mongoose-schema

So when I am executing my findByIdAndUpdate it doesn't execute my promise as expected and goes into my catch. I sent responses to postman and using `res.json(req.user.id)` and `res.json(profileFields)` . This is the response I get when I use
**profileFields**

```
{
    "user": "5b3134a0e2543b06d130a5d7",
    "handle": "wadeaston1",
    "status": "Developer",
    "skills": [
        "HTML",
        " CSS",
        " Javascipt"
    ],
    "social": {}
}
```

i'm at a loss here because all my fields are passing in the values as expected into user and $set. I don't understand why its going to my catch

```
 Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { user: req.user.id },
      { $set: profileFields },
      { new: true }
    )
      .then(profile => res.json(profile))
      .catch(err => {
        res.json("Timeout");
        console.log("HI");
      });
```

**Here is my Profile Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Scheme
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    //this will associate user by their ID
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  company: {
    type: String
  },
  website: {
    type: String
  },
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  skills: {
    //Array of strings
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  githubusername: {
    type: String
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: String
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profile", ProfileSchema);
```

Comment: What is the `err` in your `catch()`? It'll probably tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Cast to ObjectId failed for value  for { user: '5b3134a0e2543b06d130a5d7' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findByIdAndUpdate` is for finding the document to update by its `_id` value, but you need to find the document by its `user` field, so you should be using [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate) instead:

```
Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
      { user: req.user.id },
      { $set: profileFields },
      { new: true }
    )
    .then(...
```

No need to manually cast `req.user.id` to an ObjectId as Mongoose will do that for you based on the way `user` is defined in your schema.

Comment: I didn't even see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you gave, it looks like you need to turn `req.user.id` from a `string` to an `ObjectId`:

```
Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) },
  { $set: profileFields },
  { new: true }
).then( /* rest of code */
```

This assumes you did a `const mongoose = require('mongoose')` or similar.